# Stepper motor with mp3 shield Arduino

Tags: arduino, mp3, arduino-uno

For a college project I want to make a stepper motor combined with a mp3shield.

It is al working fine, but when I put them in the same code, is it acting really weird and my stepper motor starts shaking.

My code is below:

```
int sensor = A0;
int led1 = A1;
int led2 = A2;
int led3 = A3;
int led4 = A4;
int led5 = A5;
int button = 12;
int dirpin = 10;
int steppin = 11;

int buttonState;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(sensor, INPUT);
  pinMode(button, INPUT);

  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(steppin, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  buttonState = digitalRead(button);
  Serial.println(buttonState);
  delay(10);

  if(buttonState == HIGH)
  {
    rotateDeg(360, .1);
    playSong(6);
  }
}
```

The code for letting the stepper motor turn is the following:

```
void rotateDeg(float deg, float speed){ 
  int dir = (deg > 0)? HIGH:LOW;
  digitalWrite(dirpin,dir); 

  int steps = abs(deg)*(1/0.225);
  float usDelay = (1/speed) * 70;

  for(int i=0; i < steps; i++){ 
    digitalWrite(steppin, HIGH); 
    delayMicroseconds(usDelay); 

    digitalWrite(steppin, LOW); 
    delayMicroseconds(usDelay); 
  } 
}
```

The code for playing a song:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SdFat.h>
#include <SdFatUtil.h> 
#include <SFEMP3Shield.h>

SdFat sd;
SFEMP3Shield MP3player;

void playSong(int song){

  Serial.begin(9600);

  //start the shield
  sd.begin(SD_SEL, SPI_HALF_SPEED);
  MP3player.begin();

  //start playing track 1
  MP3player.playTrack(song);
}
```

I use a driver for the stepper motor with 12V 1000mA input. If I want to play a song without the motor, is works fine.
If I want to rotate the motor without sound, it works fine as well.

Hopefully you are able to help.

Thank you in advance,

NiSh

EDIT:
I have also some LEDs, which work fine. When I press a button there will be a random pattern. 
When I put it in the code like:

```
if(buttonState == HIGH)
  {
    setLed();
    rotateDeg(360, .1);

  }
```

It works like I want that it works. But if I try:

```
if(buttonState == HIGH)
  {
    playSound(4);
    rotateDeg(360, .1);

  }
```

the motor starts shaking when playing the song, and never makes that 360 degree turn.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `uno` but I would obviously suspect that the multitasking of playing the MP3 is messing with your delay durations. If those delays vary erratically, you're stepper motor can shake due to rapid, small angular velocity changes. Do you have the option of using an interrupt driven timer for the stepper?

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your quick answer.

I am a beginner with this Arduino stuff etc. so I really don't now how I could do that.

But it makes sense, though, but why starts my motor shaking? It shouldn't send any signals to the motor.

Comment: It's a real time device. It expects those signals at a precise time for smooth motion. The motor isn't smart enough to buffer the data and then operate on it smoothly. You send data, it reacts at that moment in time. So if there are variations in the timing of your data, you'll get variations in the change of speed of the motor which is equivalent to erratic accelerations. Thus, shaking. It looks like you're updating the motor very frequently (in the microseconds, or at least milliseconds). That's not much time to allow an MP3 to play in between.

Comment: Ah, yes like that. I am going to take another look at it.

So you suggest to make the delay in the stepper motor bigger?

Comment: You can try that. What's the delay between motor commands currently?

Comment: void rotateDeg(float deg, float speed){ 
  int dir = (deg > 0)? HIGH:LOW;
  digitalWrite(dirpin,dir); 

  int steps = abs(deg)*(1/0.225);
  float usDelay = (1/speed) * 70;

  for(int i=0; i < steps; i++){ 
    digitalWrite(steppin, HIGH); 
    delayMicroseconds(usDelay); 

    digitalWrite(steppin, LOW); 
    delayMicroseconds(usDelay); 
  } 
}

The code is also in the post above.


This is my current code. I tried to make it delay instead of delayMicroseconds, but that did not work out.

How should I place an interrupt, if that is needed?

Comment: The problem isn't just the delay, but whether each setting comes at a precise time interval. When nothing else is running, your delays are fairly even. When something else is running, when it's time to send that command to the motor, the mp3 player might be in the way. Increasing the delay will slow down the motor and, if too long, might not have the desired result. An interrupt would be set up to trigger very X amount of time (whatever your delay was) and it would send the command to the motor.

Comment: And how can I make that possible. I looked on the internet, but I did not find anything that I understood.

Comment: I don't know what kind of system you are working with. It may or may not allow you to use interrupts. If you're not familiar with interrupt handlers or device drivers, it will require some study. Or if your system doesn't support those things being defined, then that option is not available.

Comment: Are there, if that option is not available, other possibilities?

Comment: You could play with the delay for how often you update the motor. Try longer times.